# How can I use LINQ to retrieve entries that contain more than one property of a list within a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects which are described below.  Inside this are `IKanji` objects that contain `Priorites` objects.

I have a rather difficult thing I would like to do and would appreciate any advice / suggestions. What I would like to do is to retrieve entries that have an entry that have `Priority` of "Frequency1" have `Priority` of "Frequency2" or `Priority` of "Frequency3" from the list `entries` that I created.

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

Here's the list:

```
List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = dictionary.GetEntries().ToList();
```

Here's a view that I think might help explain the contents:

[image]

I hope the information here is enough as it seems difficult to explain what I need to retrieve.

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: it should have all three priorities?

Comment: No just one of those three priorities.  Your answer is good and I accepted.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = entries.Where(e => e.Kanjis.Any(k => k.Priorities.Contains(Priority.Frequency1) ||
k.Priorities.Contains(Priority.Frequency2) ||
k.Priorities.Contains(Priority.Frequency3)
)).ToList();
```

Considering your 2 questions, I would have made something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Priority
{
     Frequency1 = 1,
     Frequency2 = 2,
     Frequency3 = 4,
     Frequency4 = 8
}

public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    Priority Priorities { get; }
}
```

In above consider each Priority as a `bit` in an int, you can add priority by using bitwise or (`|`) :

Priorities = Priority.Frequency1 | Priority.Frequency2 // means have both priorities

To check if it has specific priority use bitwise and (`&`):

```
if((Priorities & Priority.Frequency1) == Priority.Frequency1
{
     // it contains Priority.Frequency1
}
```

Then the answer you were looking for will be like:

```
Priority p = Priority.Frequency1 | Priority.Frequency2 | Priority.Frequency3

var result = entries.Where(e => e.Kanjis.Any(k => k.Priorities & p == p)))
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, It's very impressive what can be done with LINQ.  I will accept the answer.

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm editing my answer. I want to suggest a faster solution if you like.

Comment: @Alan2 please check my answer again

Comment: Yes please.  I have a lot of records and actually want all the Frequencies from 1 to 48. I am thinking to just extend your suggestion by putting in many || clauses for each Frequency

Answer (score 2):

This could be one solution:

```
var filteredEntries = entries.Where( // Only entries
    e => e.Kanjis.Any( // which have one or more kanjis with..
        a => a.Priorities.Any( // which have one or more priorities                    
            p => p.Value == "Frequency1" // which have a value of "Frequency1"
            )));
```

I changed your `interfaces` to `classes` to make it run with some example-data:

```
public class IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; set; }
}
public class IKanji
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Initialize 3 objects. One has Priority we're searching
    List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = new List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry>()
    {
        new IJapaneseDictionaryEntry(){ Sequence = 1, Kanjis = new List<IKanji>() { new IKanji() { Priorities = new List<Priority>() { new Priority() { Value = "Frequency1" } } } } },
        new IJapaneseDictionaryEntry(){ Sequence = 2, Kanjis = new List<IKanji>() { new IKanji() { Priorities = new List<Priority>() { new Priority() { Value = "Frequency2" } } } } },
        new IJapaneseDictionaryEntry(){ Sequence = 3, Kanjis = new List<IKanji>() { new IKanji() { Priorities = new List<Priority>() { new Priority() { } } } } },
    };

    // Here's the magic:
    var filteredEntries = entries.Where( // Only entries
        e => e.Kanjis.Any( // which have one or more kanjis with..
            a => a.Priorities.Any( // which have one or more priorities                    
                p => p.Value == "Frequency1" // which have a value of "Frequency1"
                )));

    // Let's check the output
    foreach (var e in filteredEntries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Sequence);
    }
}
```